# Duplicate matplotlib plot in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm fairly new to Python and matplotlib. I want to plot something and on the right hand plot a detail of the main plot. But I don't want to duplicate the plot explicitly, given the complexity of the actual plot

MWE

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y=np.sin(x)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plot(x,y)

# I WANT TO AVOID THIS LINE
ax2.plot(x,y)
# AND USE SOMETHING LIKE ax2=ax1

ax2.set_xlim([0.5,0.7])
ax2.set_ylim(np.sin(ax2.get_xlim()))
plt.show();
```

Thanks

Comment: Create a dedicated function that does all the plotting and pass it the axes instance both times, i.e. for both `ax1` and `ax2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BigBen comment, I did the following

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y=np.sin(x)

def plotty(x, y, ax):
    ax.plot(x,y)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

plotty(x, y, ax1)

plotty(x, y, ax2)

ax2.set_xlim([0.5,0.7])
ax2.set_ylim(np.sin(ax2.get_xlim()))
plt.show();
```

My actual function computes PSD based on a list of parameters, putting several spectra on the same plot. This syntax is fairly elegant and compact.

Thanks

Comment: The function you define is totally unnecessary, just say, e.g., `ax1.plot(x, y)`

Comment: I agree. It's just an example. In my case, my plot is generated using 10 lines of `ax1.plot()`, calling several data series. I want to copy `ax1` into `ax2`, and then reset the axis limits, to zoom into a smaller region of the whole plot. I don't want to write twice those 10 lines, which would be contained in my `plotty` function